# Mongo daemon crashes and user inexplicably logged out - how to diagnose

Tags: python, mongodb, unix, mapreduce, pymongo

I'm running mongodb version 2.6 on mac osx yosemite.

I'm running a fairly complex/computationally-intensive update pipeline in pymongo, with a few mapreduce jobs on a collection with ~4million documents. Now, in the midst of this update pipeline, there is a perplexing crash. Here is what happens:

1. I start the mongo daemon, with the output going to a log file.
2. I run the python script, and wait for it to finish, with stdout and stderr written to another log file.
3. I return to my machine a few hours later, and find that my user session seems to have been killed (I'm logged out), the mongo daemon is no longer running, and my job didn't finish.

But in the log files, there is no trace of an error. How can I track down the bug leading to this crash and inexplicable logout? Here is the code I'm using

`$ mongod --logpath=mongo_log.txt
 $ python update_script.py >> update_log.txt 2>&1`

Comment: you are starting the mongodb from shell, so if for some reason your shell dies, the mongodb and python will go with it without any explanation; I'd recommend narrowing the reasons and running mongodb inside [`screen`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314747/how-to-process-numbers-in-a-line-individually) for example.

Comment: You might want to use the official mongo docker containers. Please note that running mongod on OSX for production purposes is not advised.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I'm not really using this in production. Just in a research lab. But duly noted. What is the preferred alternative?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala That link in your comment was seemingly unrelated. I guess the crux of my question is precisely how to catch my shell being killed.

Comment: if the question is how to catch your shell being killed, then there is not much programming related there any more, guess this is more like superuser or unix & linux :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Fair enough. I've posted a more pointed version of the question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193141/catch-diagnose-user-process-being-killed-inexplicably-logged-out-automatically]).  Not sure if that means this one should be closed.

Comment: Well, [cross-posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu/64073#64073) is discouraged - since here are no answers, you can always delete your question (you can save a copy of the text for yourself in a file)